# How To Test For Type of Beautiful Soup Object?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

This may be a very basic Python question, although I am running across it in Beautiful Soup.

The basic thing I want to do is to extract only the output text from an HTML file.

For example in the HTML file included below I would like to extract only 0123, abc, def and ghi but not the tags and attributes.

As best I understand BS I should be able to recurse through the descendants of the HTML tag and include only things that are NavigableStrings.

The problem is I don't know how to write the if statement to test for the type. See the comment in the python code below.

Any solutions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>0123</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>abc</p>def
        <a href="wxy.z">ghi</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>


# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('simple.html', 'r') as inf:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(inf.read(), 'lxml')
    for e in soup('html'):
        for d in e.descendants:
            print d     # HERE I WANT TO SKIP EXCEPT FOR NAVIGABLE STRINGS
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are looking for navigable strings, your condition should be:

```
if isinstance(d, bs4.element.NavigableString):
    print d
```

And don't forget to `import bs4` at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks. Not importing BS4 was the problem.